# How to handle blank space in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to replace null values with a blank space but its throwing an error in snowflake.

```
select 
    case when CALL_DATE IS NULL then ' ' ELSE CALL_DATE end as CALL_DATE_NEW
from Table_x
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Timestamp '' is not recognized

Comment: This is due to the data type of the ''. Review this article: https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/Query-Failed-With-Error-Timestamp-2020-09-01-is-not-recognized

Comment: You can also use NULLIF. Details: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/nullif.html

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the derived column CALL_DATE_NEW gets implicitly cast to type timestamp. As the error indicates, you can't specify a space as a timestamp. You can; however, specify a timestamp as a varchar:

```
create or replace temp table X (CALL_DATE timestamp);
insert into X values ('2021-12-03'), (null);

select case when CALL_DATE IS NULL then ' ' ELSE CALL_DATE end as CALL_DATE_NEW from x; -- Timestamp '' is not recognized

select case when CALL_DATE IS NULL then ' ' ELSE to_varchar(CALL_DATE) end as CALL_DATE_NEW from x; -- Works by keeping the types consistent
```

Answer (score 0):

Date data types can be null or contain data and/or time data.
They cannot contain Space. Sorry.